# Filesystem to use on SSD for cross platform Linux Windows software development

Tags: ssd, filesystems, operating-systems

I know the question "which cross os filesystem" has been asked again and again with `ntfs` being the go to, but I would like to determine which would be best for a specific use case.

I'm a software engineer. I would like to know which would be best for the SSD primarily for software development under Linux, but also be compatible with Windows. Compiling the repos I work on destroys and recreates often a full gigabyte per build, so I need to consider the life of the SSD. I would also like to keep a Steam library on it for both Linux and Windows. This drive would contain no OS partitions but would contain important data for both Linux and Windows, such as programs and repositories.

Now, all that considered, really my question comes down to which filesystem is best for the SSD, but is also compatible with Linux and Windows. Or does it even matter? Perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree and ruminating over something trivial. I've searched high and low for trying to determine this answer from a heavy write oriented perspective on and SSD, but no such answer exist.

Comment: Windows only supports NTFS. Windows Subsystem for Linux also supports it. Linux also supports NTFS.

Comment: What makes your "*specific use case*" is so unique that it would invalidate the "*go to*" answer?

Comment: I suppose nothing does then. Closing the question gave me the answer. Thanks.